# im trying to get an input from user using an edittext then convert its string to int to validate

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to get the string input from EditText be converted to int and validate the int using the if statement.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button but5;
public EditText et;
public String hello;
public Integer myNum;
public void main5(){
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    hello = et.getText().toString();
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
    but5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    but5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(myNum >= 18){
                Intent a = new Intent(Main3Activity.this,Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            } else {
                Intent a = new Intent(Main3Activity.this,Main4Activity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

so you are a beginner. Remember that each time you ask question please copy and paste the log cat error too. It will be easy for us to debug your error.
At the moment just try
`myNum = Integer.parseInt(hello);`

instead of

`myNum = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());`

Comment: it show's no error but when i when i tried to run it the app force close before it can enter this activity

Comment: so in android studio there is an option "android moniter" just copy everything you see red